# How to enable screen recording for WebRTC on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I want to know how to enable screen recording for WebRTC on Android application while I using WebView as WebRTC context

I know about getUserMedia and RTCPeerConnection.addStream, I also know about how to recording the screen with MediaProjection, VirtualDisplay but I don't know how to addStream with recording screen stream